# ООП Полиморфизм в рhp

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Добрий день. 
Есть такая функция:

```
public function category($id)
 {
     $page=isset($_GET['page'])? intval($_GET['page']):1;
     $news = new NewsModel();
     $this->data['page']=new Pagination
     ([
         'itemsCount' => $news->getCountNews ( $id ),
         'itemsPerPage' => $this->itemPerPage,
         'currentPage' => $page
     ]);
     $getNews = $news->getNews($id, $page);
     if (!$getNews) {
         $this->render404();
     }
     $this->data['news'] = $getNews;
     $this->render($this->view);
 }
```

Нужно переопердилить 4 строчку кода

```
$news = new NewsModel();
```

на

```
$news = new AdminModel();
```

Пытался сделать в основном контроллере (BaseController):

```
protected $model;
public function category($id)
 {
     $page=isset($_GET['page'])? intval($_GET['page']):1;
     $news = $this->model;
     $this->data['page']=new Pagination
     ([
         'itemsCount' => $news->getCountNews ( $id ),
         'itemsPerPage' => $this->itemPerPage,
         'currentPage' => $page
     ]);
     $getNews = $news->getNews($id, $page);
     if (!$getNews) {
         $this->render404();
     }
     $this->data['news'] = $getNews;
     $this->render($this->view);
 }
```

поменял
$news = new NewsModel()
потом

```
class AdminController extends BaseController
{
    protected $model=new AdminModel();
}
```

но при создании

```
protected $model=new AdminModel();
```

IDE подчеркивает красным,значит так не  делаеться .[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добрый вечер можно узнать NewsModel и AdminModel что из себя представляет? Это Классы?

Comment: Это модель где я получаю новости sql запросом.Это все модели.

Comment: Извините но вы не ответили на мой вопрос и пока я не узнаю это нечем не смогу помочь вам?

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос посмотрите так буде понятней...

Comment: Свойства в области видимости принимают не все типы данных `protected $model=str| int | array`. Для этих целей можно создать setter

Comment: И да области видимости присваиваются в не метнодов,их объявляют в начале класса .Для этих целей можно создать setter `public function setModel(){ $this->model =new AdminModel() }`

Answer (score 4):

Вы шли почти в правильном направлении.
Свойства в области видимости принимают не все типы данных.

Допустимые типы для значений

```
protected $model = str | int | array | boolean | heredocs | nowdocs;
```

Только надо было создать геттер для этих целей (Метод который вернет свойство с присвоенным значением):

```
class AdminController extends BaseController
{
    protected $model; // При таком раскладе он тут вообще не нужен 

    protcted function getModel(){
        return new AdminModel(); // Не абстрактный класс
    }
}
```

А потом его и вызывать

```
public function category($id)
 {
     //..................
     $news = $this->getModel();
     //..............
 }
```